# How can receive UDP data from Python UDP client in MatLab.

Tags: python, matlab, sockets

Hi I programmed UDP client in Python. This is the code.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
x=0.4
message = str(x)

try:

    # Send data
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)

    # Receive response
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive'
    data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

Now I would like to receive that data in my MatLab/Simulink block. I have done some research, and what found is that Instrument Control Toolbox can be use UDP object to get the data. Or go to the File Exchange and grabbed the Simple UDP Communications App code. It is just one function, judp, that allows me to send and receive UDP packets.

Is this going to work with my python UDP client?
Is there any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am struggling with the same problem and judp does not seem to work with my python UDP client.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is standardized since 1980. While I agree, sometimes the same 3 letter abbreviation does not mean both like to talk to each other, in this case you can rely on UDP libraries to be compatible. If it does not work, either you made a mistake or some firewall or similar is interfering.

You found two of the easy to use options. The first one requires a license for the toolbox. Both will work and I don't see disadvantages.

There are plenty of other options, but they will all end up in a more complicated solution. You could for example write a python library to receive the data and call it from MATLAB. This is probably pointless since MATLAB can do UDP.